# How to list all entries between many to many relationships and indicate when there is a match

Tags: sql, outer-join

I've created a database and I would like to be able to retrieve all entries from 2 tables that are in a many to many relationship and indicate when there is a match.

[image: SQL Schema]

You can find exemple with some dummy data in the screenshot attached with the expected result.

[image: Result]

I'm not able to see how can I list all operators and all standards on the same table independently. I've done some test with full outer join but the result is not satisfactory.

```sql
SELECT o.Nom,s.Nom_Standard
from Formation as f
    full OUTER join Operateurs as o
        on o.Id_Operateur = f.Fk_Operateur
    full OUTER JOIN Standards as s 
        on s.Id_Standard = ps.Fk_Standard
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're only storing a relationship for things that are `done`, to produce a result set of all combinations you need to store all relationships, you then need an additional field on your middle table showing whether the relationship is `done` or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to get the operators and standards:

```
select o.Nom, s.Nom_Standard
from Operateurs o cross join
     Standards s ;
```

If you want to bring in information from `Formation`, use a `left join`:

```
select o.Nom, s.Nom_Standard,
       (case when f.IdOperateur is not null then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as is_done
from Operateurs o cross join
     Standards s left join
     Formation f
     on o.Id_Operateur = f.Fk_Operateur
        s.Id_Standard = f.Fk_Standard;
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it has done the job for my case :)

Answer (score 0):

See my comment on your question, however there is a way of getting what you want:

```sql
SELECT o.Nom, s.Nom_Standard, (CASE WHEN ISNULL(f.Id_Formation) THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END) AS done
FROM Operateurs o
INNER JOIN Standards s
LEFT OUTER JOIN Formation f ON f.Fk_Operateur=o.Id_Operateur AND f.Fk_Standard=s.Id_Standard
ORDER BY o.Id_Operateur
```

**But** this is not using the middle table as a standard many to many join table and so could cause future confusion.